# How to format a file in vscode without formatting an object

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

While formatting a file in vs code I want contents of an object in a single line.
For example, I want the object to be in this format

[image]

But on format this is the result I am getting

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Comment: Don't post code images. Just post the actual text.